# breaks slick slider in tab

Tags: jquery, slick.js

When switching tabs, the slider was falling off, but I solved this problem method .slick('setPosition'); but now there is a second problem when I click very very fast many times on the name of tab1..., it breaks the slider:( [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexgrimm87/mfvr6p8q/1/)

```
function tabs() {
  $('.tab-item').not(':first').hide();
  $('.js-tab .tab-list li').click(function() {
    $('.js-tab .tab-list li').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    $('.js-tab .tab-item').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
    $('.slider').slick('setPosition');
  }).eq(0).addClass('active');
}

function slider(selector) {
  $(selector).slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    arrows: false
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  tabs();
  slider('.slider');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.debounce. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mfvr6p8q/2/)

```
$('.js-tab .tab-list li').click($.debounce(250, function() {
  $('.js-tab .tab-list li').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
  $('.js-tab .tab-item').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
  $('.slider').slick('setPosition');
})).eq(0).addClass('active');
```

Be aware that it requires another library: [jquery-throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/)

Comment: If without a break to click with the usual speed of taboos still have this slider bug. Is it possible to implement without plug-ins?